# Why the title page does not show up?

Tags: titles

Here is the code. The PDF file start with the TOC not the title page. I've also tried to place \maketitle several places, only generates errs.

```
\documentclass[]{colorbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\title{My book} 
\author{John}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Good to Know}
\section{Background}
Provide some background.
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands `\title` and `\author` usually do not print a title or author, but set internal macros to be used inside `\maketitle`. And environment `titlepage` is not for printing titles defined using `\title` and `\author` but to make a free titlepage. So usually you have to remove the `titlepage` environment and use `\maketitle`.

However, I always get error messages because of undefined `\LocallyStopLineNumbers` and `\ResumeLineNumbers` with class `colorbook`. So to have an error free LaTeX run, I need something like:

```
\documentclass[]{colorbook}
\providecommand*{\LocallyStopLineNumbers}{}
\providecommand*{\ResumeLineNumbers}{}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{My book} 
\author{John}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Good to Know}
\section{Background}
Provide some background.
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

Comment: You may even write `\title` and `\author` and other commands regarding the titlepage (like `\date`) in the preamble.

Comment: @Latin-TeX You may, but it's nothing wrong in putting them into the body. And if you want to use, i.e., `babel` shorthands, it's easier to do it after `\begin{document}`

Comment: You are right. I like it more to have it before `\begin{document}` but it is mostly a matter of flavor, I guess.